# Спрайт выше чем UI

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я столкнулся с такой проблемой: работаю с материалами впервые на unity2d. Накинул материал на 2d спрайт. Он хорошо работает. Однако он загораживает джостик. Хотя стоит ниже него(-1). Подскажите пожалуйста, как это исправить.

[image: Сам джостик]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

За последовательность рендера отвечает [Sorting layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TagManager.html)

То есть ты сам выставил такую последовательность рендрера

По этой теме есть и официальный видеотуториал:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZzcyREamMUo